# React iteration through object &render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iteration, jsx

```
class PortfolioDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      portfolio: [],
      PF: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var params = new URLSearchParams();

    params.append("post_id", this.props.postID);
    params.append("getportfolio", 1);

    var self = this;
    axios
      .get(this.props.dataURL, { params })
      .then(function(response) {
        self.setState({
          portfolio: {
            title: response.data[0].title,
            data: response.data
          },
          PF: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {});
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {

  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.PF);
    const portfolioQuals = Object.keys(this.state.PF).map(function(key) {
        var item = this.state.PF[key];
        console.log(key);
        return (
          <tr key={key}>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
        );
    });
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>
          {this.state.portfolio.title}
        </h1>
        <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {portfolioQuals}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I iterate through object and render it below. My const broken and show nothing. I already tryed everything - Object.keys, Object.map, for..in - nothing helps. I've got very specific response from json server, could someone give me a direction point.
Here's JSON structure

```
{
0: {
"title": "Awesome title"
},
"_stp_postmeta_form_of_participation": [
  "Awesome text"
],
"_stp_postmeta_result": [
  "Awesome text "
],
"_stp_postmeta_description_of_the_event": [
  "Awesome text"
],
"_stp_postmeta_year_of_holding_receipt": [
  "09.04.2016"
],
"_stp_postmeta_type_of_event_organization": [
  "Awesome text"
],
"_thumbnail_id": [
  "116243"
],
"_stp_postmeta_document_individual": [
  "/files/portfolio/stud002240804/54524dd19f48d90c1bb0a46751f05d6b.jpg"
],
"_stp_approved_individual": [
  "1"
],
"_stp_approved_documents_education": [
  "1"
],
"_stp_approved_document_professional": [
  "1"
],
"_stp_approved_document_scientific": [
  "1"
],
"_stp_approved_documents_learning": [
  "1"
],
"_stp_approved_document_promotion": [
  "1"
],
"_stp_approved_document_publication": [
  "1"
],
"_stp_approved_document_seniority": [
  "1"
],
}
```

Comment: What king of mapping do you need in you Layout.

Comment: As usual - key-value.  return (
          <tr key={key}>
            <td>{key}</td>
            <td>{value}</td>
          </tr>
        );

Comment: What do you expect as key and value from the above JSON response

Comment: for example - key - _stp_postmeta_form_of_participation, value - "Awesome text"

Comment: on last question, does your array `"_stp_postmeta_form_of_participation": [
  "Awesome text"
],` contain multiple elements of a single element

Comment: it is array with a single element

Answer (score 0):

You need to `map` over with the `Object.keys` and then check if the object value is an array using `instanceof` and then return the first value of the array if you only need one otherwise map over it again.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
   data = {
    0: {
    "title": "Awesome title"
    },
    "_stp_postmeta_form_of_participation": [
      "Awesome text"
    ],
    "_stp_postmeta_result": [
      "Awesome text "
    ],
    "_stp_postmeta_description_of_the_event": [
      "Awesome text"
    ],
    "_stp_postmeta_year_of_holding_receipt": [
      "09.04.2016"
    ],
    "_stp_postmeta_type_of_event_organization": [
      "Awesome text"
    ],
    "_thumbnail_id": [
      "116243"
    ],
    "_stp_postmeta_document_individual": [
      "/files/portfolio/stud002240804/54524dd19f48d90c1bb0a46751f05d6b.jpg"
    ],
    "_stp_approved_individual": [
      "1"
    ],
    "_stp_approved_documents_education": [
      "1"
    ],
    "_stp_approved_document_professional": [
      "1"
    ],
    "_stp_approved_document_scientific": [
      "1"
    ],
    "_stp_approved_documents_learning": [
      "1"
    ],
    "_stp_approved_document_promotion": [
      "1"
    ],
    "_stp_approved_document_publication": [
      "1"
    ],
    "_stp_approved_document_seniority": [
      "1"
    ],
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <table>
              {Object.keys(this.data).map((key, index) => {
                  if( this.data[key] instanceof Array) {
                  return (
                      <tr key={key}>
                         <td>{key}</td>
                         <td>{this.data[key][0]}</td>
                      </tr>
                  )
                  }
                  return null;
              })}
            </table>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean what I mean - nothing works within my code. Your solution may be right in stand alone script, but in my code it is broken. Whatever - I made it by myself, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a JSX6 method and made all magic happens there

```
 iterateData(json) {

    var iter = [];
    for (var key in json) {
      console.log(key);
      console.log(json[key]);
      iter.push(
        <tr key={key}>
          <td>{key}</td>
          <td>{json[key]}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
    return iter;
  }

return (
  <div className="container">
    <h1>
      {this.state.portfolio.title}
    </h1>
    <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {this.iterateData(this.state.PF)}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```